# Windows 10 users can't connect to encrypted Samba shared folder

Tags: windows-10, encryption, samba

I'm on Fedora 31 and I've set up a password protected Samba share, however as I'm on an untrusted network I would like to encrypt the traffic to protect myself from monitoring, so I've enabled `smb encrypt = required`.

I will have Windows 10, MacOS, and Linux clients, and so far MacOS and GNU+Linux clients are connecting without problem, but the Windows 10 clients cannot connect (through Windows Explorer). Is there anything in particular that needs to be enabled to allow for this?

The `required` flag will deny access to clients that don't connect with encryption, so is it possible Windows 10 users are failing because of this?

**smb.conf:**

```
[global]
        workgroup = SIMERNES
        security = user

        passdb backend = tdbsam

        printing = cups
        printcap name = cups
        load printers = yes
        cups options = raw
        smb encrypt = required

[shared]
        comment = Shared Folder
        path = /home/smbuser/sambashare
        valid users = smbuser
        public = yes
        writable = yes
        write list = samba
        create mask = 0777
        directory mask = 0777
        printable = no
```

`smbd -V` returns `4.11.4`.

Comment: What version of SMB have you configured Samba to use?

Comment: I think it is using version 4.11.4 due to the call to ```smbd -V```. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: `smbd` is actually the name of the Samba.  `4.11.4` is the version of Samba you have installed.  I am asking for which version of SMB you have configured Samba to use.  The only choices to this question by the way is either (SMBv1, SMBv2, or SMBv3).

Comment: I didn't have anything set so judging from the smb.conf manual https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html the default value for ```server min protocol``` was ```LANMAN1``` and the ```server max protocol``` was ```SMB3```.

Comment: I would set the `server min protocol` to `SMB3` and verify if the Windows client can connect.  This might or might not effect the other clients, however, SMBv1 is insecure so it shouldn't be used anyways. (Which would be allowed given your minimum protocol is `LANMAN1 `).

Comment: Which Windows 10 version is used (date)?